# How to trigger a Travis rebuild for my pull-request from a GitHub comment?

Tags: github, triggers, continuous-integration, travis-ci, cloudbees

**How to trigger a Travis rebuild for my pull-request from a github comment?**

After a pull-request is created on Github, the Travis PR builds triggers. And if we want to re-trigger a build, we could press the `Restart Job` button on Travis GUI:

[image]

But is there a way to trigger the `Restart Job` by listening to the comments in the Github Pull-Request and perhaps look for a specific comment text, e.g. `[CI: Restart build]`?

In Jenkins with Cloudbees, it's possible to set the trigger phrase in the `Build Triggers` section, e.g.

[image]

**Is that possible in Travis too?**

**How to trigger a Travis rebuild for my pull-request from a github comment?**

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't seem to be possible from one side.

However, what you *could* try is to use [GitHub Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to listen for comments on Pull Requests. This could trigger a custom script on your server, which looks for commands inside a [Pull Request comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestreviewcommentevent) (e.g. `[CI: Restart build]`).

If the pull request contains the command, you could then trigger a new build with the [Travis API](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/).

It may be some work to realize this, but this could be a nice workaround.